# I rest at attention - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

In your belly I'm cause for alarm,
But among friends I delight and charm.

With shimmering scales and all-seeing eyes
I rest at attention - **who am I?**

Comment: @downvoter - your constructive criticism welcome, as this is only my second puzzle here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess:

> Butterfly

In your belly I'm cause for alarm,

> Butterflies in the stomach-common idiom for anxiety

But among friends I delight and charm.

> Another idiom- Social butterfly- A person who has many friends and acquaintances.

With shimmering scales and all-seeing eyes

> Shimmering scales may refer to the wings of the butterfly which usually change their color. All seeing eyes- maybe the way it is searching for nectar..
>
>  Intended explanation: a butterfly's wings are covered with iridescent scales, and they have a very wide range of vision, thanks to their literal bug-eyes!

I rest at attention

> Butterfly is always the centre of all attention
>
>  Intended explanation: Most butterflies rest with their wings upright ("at attention" - as opposed to moths, which typically lay flat).

Comment: That's the one! but the only explanation that matches is the first - there's another common idiom, and for the rest, think about the biology..

Comment: What about now??

Comment: Got the idiom! And the scales, basically - they are literally covered with tiny iridescent ones. I'll go ahead and accept, for the other two: [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/do-butterflies-see-behind) was the clue for the eyes, and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_butterflies_and_moths#Resting_posture) for "resting at attention". Hopefully I didn't make it too obscure knowledge, at least easily google-able :)

Comment: cool, u can edit the answer...

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> hunger

In your belly it cause for alarm

> when we are hungry it cause an alarm to kill the hunger

But among friend ,i delight and charm

> when we are hungry we sat at the restaurant or dominos

With shimmering scales and all eyes seeing I rest at attention

> when we with our friend at restaurant... And we make noise as we sip bear with food..then all peoples at restaurant see our act with all of their attention eyes...then our hunger gone or can say rest

Comment: Creative! I like your explanations for the first two lines, but the answer I have in mind fits the second part more literally.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Pterois (Lionfish)

In your belly I'm cause for alarm,

> They are very venomous

But among friends I delight and charm.

> but they're very pretty.

With shimmering scales and all-seeing eyes

> It's a scaly fish with huge sticking-out eyes

I rest at attention

> Because of all the spines it kind of looks like it's saluting when at rest.

But perhaps I'm being too literal :p

Comment: Not the answer, but they are very pretty :) I will say you're right to take part of it literally.